# Tailwind/CSS using custom fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, tailwind-css

I have a project where I need to use custom fonts. But I have no idea how to use this in my HTML. I have searched online how to do this, but all examples use a font that is contained in one file. My font is contained in multiple files.

How do I specify which specific font of the CircularStd I want to use on each element?

This is a screenshot of my index.scss file which contains the tailwind imports and the definition of my font:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An approach to this would be creating a custom font class in your `tailwindconfig.js` and extending it to your default tailwind theme. For example, if you're using Google Fonts and you want to use the font *Manrope* for a specific header, you can extend the fontFamily variant like so:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'manrope': 'Manrope',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to use this custom class declare it in your html by following the syntax `font-{fontFamily}`. So in this case, we're going to use font-manrope.

```
<h4 class="font-manrope">I'm a header using the font Manrope</h4>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you think that your font has many files and you need them all then why not create a `@fontface` for each one although this is not the best practice, you are supposed to for example to choose the file with the light and standard font and you create the `@fontface` based on it and include it's file the others like the bold and italics can eventually be done using CSS but the most important thing is that you have your font implemented.
so for example you will add your font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

and if you want it to be bold and italic use

```
p{
font-weight:600;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

I hope that would help!

Comment: So I need to import all different files in a main font file and then import that main file in the font face?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by import all different files in the main file, all you need to do is to import just one file preferably the light standard one by implementing it in the fontface, then your font will be working.

Comment: But how do i define the book style? When i try to do `font-style: book;` this style doesn't take.

Comment: what do you mean by book style? `book` is not a valid value to the `font-style` that's why it doesn't work